# kivy - TypeError: descriptor 'property' requires a 'kivy._event.EventDispatcher' object but received a 'method_descriptor'

Tags: python, kivy

I am building an android app using kivy and buildozer. App crashes on start and I found this TypeError. So iget the logs using logcat and so this error after some lines from traceback. I'm using Kivy 1.9.0 and Python 2.7.9 Is there a way to fix this ? Please tell me how to fix this one. Thank you. T_T

```
02-13 04:57:08.929 25243 25376 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
02-13 04:57:08.930 25243 25376 I python  :    File "/home/dex/Desktop/avac-app/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 1, in <module>
02-13 04:57:08.931 25243 25376 I python  :    File "/home/dex/Desktop/avac-app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/avacremote/kivy/base.py", line 27, in <module>
02-13 04:57:08.931 25243 25376 I python  :    File "/home/dex/Desktop/avac-app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/avacremote/kivy/event.py", line 8, in <module>
02-13 04:57:08.932 25243 25376 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 891, in init kivy._event (kivy/_event.c:14871)
02-13 04:57:08.933 25243 25376 I python  :  TypeError: descriptor 'property' requires a 'kivy._event.EventDispatcher' object but received a 'method_descriptor'
```

Here is the whole log (logcat).
[log](http://www.mediafire.com/file/351fa5dto7wnn3n/log1.txt/file)

Link for my codes. 
https://github.com/kivy/kivy/files/2856367/mycodes.zip

main.py

```
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.uix.button import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App
import time
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from threading import Thread


print("step1 done!")
scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_creds.json', scope)

print("step2 done!")

#authorize the account for using gspread api

client = gspread.authorize(credentials)

print("step3 done!")

# Open Client worksheet from spreadsheet with one shot
status = client.open('automated-vac-status').sheet1
print("status done")


# Open Status worksheet from spreadsheet with one shot
mode = client.open('automated-vac-mode').sheet1
print("mode done")


# Open Mode worksheet from spreadsheet with one shot
clientsheet = client.open('automated-vac-client').sheet1

print("step4 done!")


global mode_var

def getMode():
    print("Getting Mode.")
    currmode = mode.cell(1,1).value
    currmode = int(currmode)
    return currmode

def setMode(mode_val):
    print("Setting Mode.")
    mode.update_cell(1,1, mode_val)             

mode_var = getMode()


class RootWidget(FloatLayout):
    print('Root')


    def toAutomatic(self):
        print("toAutomatic called")
        self.ids.AutoButton.text = "CHANGE TO AUTOMATIC"
        self.ids.ManButton.disabled = False
        self.ids.StandButton.disabled = False
        self.ids.AutoButton.disabled = True
        self.ids.ToggleButtonAC.disabled = True
        self.ids.ToggleButtonFan.disabled = True
        mode = 0
        setMode(mode)
        self.ids.L5.text = "AUTOMATIC MODE"


    def toManual(self):
    print("toManual called")
        self.ids.ManButton.disabled = True
    self.ids.AutoButton.disabled = False
    self.ids.StandButton.disabled = False
    self.ids.ToggleButtonAC.disabled = False
        self.ids.ToggleButtonFan.disabled = False
    mode = 1
    setMode(mode)
    self.ids.L5.text = "MANUAL MODE"


    def toStandby(self):
        print("toStandby called")
        self.ids.ManButton.disabled = False
        self.ids.AutoButton.disabled = False
        self.ids.StandButton.disabled = True
        self.ids.ToggleButtonAC.disabled = True
        self.ids.ToggleButtonFan.disabled = True
        mode = 2
        setMode(mode)
        status.update_cell(1,5,0)
        status.update_cell(1,6,0)
        self.ids.ToggleButtonAC.text = "OFF"
        self.ids.ToggleButtonAC.state = 'normal'
        self.ids.ToggleButtonFan.text = "OFF"
        self.ids.ToggleButtonFan.state = 'normal'
        self.ids.L5.text = "STANDBY MODE"


    def getStateAC(self):
        aircon_status = status.cell(1,5).value
        aircon_status = int(aircon_status)

        if aircon_status == 0:
            self.ids.ToggleButtonAC.text = "OFF"
            return 'normal'
        else:
            self.ids.ToggleButtonAC.text = "ON"
            return 'down'

    def getStateFan(self):
        fan_status = status.cell(1,6).value
        fan_status = int(fan_status)

        if fan_status == 0:
            self.ids.ToggleButtonFan.text = "OFF"
            return 'normal'
        else:
            self.ids.ToggleButtonFan.text = "ON"
            return 'down'

    def setStateAC(self):
        if self.ids.ToggleButtonAC.state == 'normal':
            self.ids.ToggleButtonAC.text = "OFF"
            status.update_cell(1,5, 0)
        elif self.ids.ToggleButtonAC.state == 'down':
            self.ids.ToggleButtonAC.text = "ON"
            status.update_cell(1,5, 1)

    def setStateFan(self):
        if self.ids.ToggleButtonFan.state == 'normal':
            self.ids.ToggleButtonFan.text = "OFF"
            status.update_cell(1,6, 0)
        elif self.ids.ToggleButtonFan.state == 'down':
            self.ids.ToggleButtonFan.text = "ON"
            status.update_cell(1,6, 1)

    def ConditionAC(self):
        aircon = status.cell(1,5).value
        aircon = int(aircon)
        if aircon == 0:
            return 'OFF'
        else:
            return 'ON'

    def ConditionFan(self):
        fan = status.cell(1,6).value
        fan = int(fan)
        if fan == 0:
            return 'OFF'
        else:
            return 'ON'

    def getTemperature(self):
        mode = getMode()
        print(mode)

        if mode == 0:
            prevmode = mode
            self.toAutomatic()
        elif mode == 1:
            prevmode = mode
            self.toManual()
        elif mode == 2:
            prevmode = mode
            self.toStandby()
        Thread(target=self.autoMode).start()
        temp = status.cell(1,1).value
        return ''+temp+' C'

    def getHumidity(self):
        temp = status.cell(1,2).value
        return ''+temp+'%'

    def autoMode(self):
        prevmode = 0
    while True:
            mode = getMode()
            print(mode)
            if prevmode != mode:
                if mode == 0:
                    prevmode = mode
                    self.toAutomatic()
                elif mode == 1:
                    prevmode = mode
                    self.toManual()
                elif mode == 2:
                    prevmode = mode
                    self.toStandby()
            #fetch data
            temperature = status.cell(1,1).value
            humidity = status.cell(1,2).value
            aircon = status.cell(1,5).value
            fan = status.cell(1,6).value
            #something data
            temperature = float(temperature)
            temperature = "{0:.2f}".format(temperature)
            humidity = float(humidity)
            humidity = "{0:.2f}".format(humidity)
            aircon = int(aircon)
            fan = int(fan)
            #tailor data
            temperature = ''+temperature+' C'
            humidity = ''+humidity+' %'
            #update views
            self.ids.LabelTempValue.text = temperature
            self.ids.LabelHumValues.text = humidity
            if aircon == 0:
                self.ids.ToggleButtonAC.text = "OFF"
                self.ids.ToggleButtonAC.state = 'normal'
            else:
                self.ids.ToggleButtonAC.text = "ON"
                self.ids.ToggleButtonAC.state = 'down'
            if fan == 0:
                self.ids.ToggleButtonFan.text = "OFF"
                self.ids.ToggleButtonFan.state = 'normal'
            else:
                self.ids.ToggleButtonFan.text = "ON"
                self.ids.ToggleButtonFan.state = 'down'
            print("ended update")
            time.sleep(3)
        return





class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()
if '__main__' == __name__:
    MainApp().run()
```

main.kv

```
<RootWidget>:
# this is the rule for your root widget, defining it's look and feel.
GridLayout:
    cols: 2
    padding: [80,20]
    spacing: [80,20]
    Label:
        text: 'Air Conditioner'
        id: L1
    ToggleButton:
        state: root.getStateAC()
        id: ToggleButtonAC
        background_color: [1,1,1,1]
        on_press: root.setStateAC()
        disabled: False
    Label:
        id: L2
        text: 'Fan'
    ToggleButton:
        state: root.getStateFan()
        id: ToggleButtonFan
        background_color: [1,1,1,1]
        on_press: root.setStateFan()
        disabled: False
    Label:
        id: LabelTemp
        text: 'Temperature:'
    Label:
        id: LabelTempValue
        text: root.getTemperature()
        background_color: [1,1,1,1]
    Label:
        id: LabelHum
        text: 'Humidity:'
    Label:
        id: LabelHumValues
        text: root.getHumidity()
        background_color: [1,1,1,1]
    Button:
        id: StandButton
        on_press: root.toStandby()
        text: 'CHANGE TO STANDBY'
        background_color: [1,3,.9,9]
        disabled: False
    Button:
        id: AutoButton
        on_press: root.toAutomatic()
        text: 'CHANGE TO AUTOMATIC'
        background_color: [2,2,.8,1]
        disabled: False
    Button:
        id: ManButton
        on_press: root.toManual()
        text: 'CHANGE TO MANUAL'
        background_color: [2,1,.8,1]
        disabled: False

    Label:
        id: L5
        text: ""
```

Comment: show complete message error

Comment: Also post a more minimal example, it's hard to read through all this code.

Comment: I've put the link for the log file. I'm sorry for late response.

Comment: @DrCreampuff - did you successfully solve that problem, am facing that too.

Answer (score 0):

you probably use the wrong cython version. please check here https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/deps-cython.html